# How can I pipe the results of grep to a perl one liner?

Tags: bash, perl, grep, pipe

I have a grep command that find the files that need a value replaced. Then I have a perl one liner that needs to be executed on each file to replace a variables found in that file.

How can I pipe the results of my grep command to the perl one liner?

```
grep -Irc "/env/file1/" /env/scripts/ | cut -d':' -f1 | sort | uniq

/env/scripts/config/MainDocument.pl
/env/scripts/config/MainDocument.pl2
/env/scripts/config/MainDocument.pl2.bak


perl -p -i.bak -e 's{/env/file1/}{/env/file2/}g' /env/scripts/config/MainDocument.pl
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide feedback on the provided answers @millsofmn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `$(...)` bash syntax.

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's{/env/file1/}{/env/file2/}g' $(grep -Irc "/env/file1/" /env/scripts/ | cut -d':' -f1 | sort | uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd forget the perl one liner to use xargs and sed instead.

```
grep -Irc "/env/file1/" /env/scripts/ | cut -d':' -f1 | sort | uniq  | xargs sed -ibak ':/env/file1/:/env/file2/:'
```